# Concatenation 2 variable PHP

Tags: php, string, concatenation

This is not the first time I encountered the problem. I have 2 variables in PHP of type string. When both of them are not empty I want something like this :

```
 echo $var1 . ',&nbsp;' . $var2;
```

My problem is that sometimes `$var1` or `$var2` could be empty so  the coma is floating. I try this :

```
 echo $var1 && $var2 ? $var1 . ',&nbsp;' . $var2 : $var1 || $var2;
```

But when we are in the right condition, it send `1`. I hope the only way is not to test `$var1 && $var2` then test `$var1` and then test `$var2`.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if statement in the middle of concatenation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13089747/if-statement-in-the-middle-of-concatenation)

Comment: Unlike some languages, PHP's `||` operator just returns a boolean, not which of the two variables satisfied the test

Comment: what do you want to actually display ? 
$var1 . ',&nbsp;' . $var2 if both are not empty and the one which is not empty if the other is empty ? something else ?

Comment: `IF (in_doubt) { do_it_longhand(); ) {`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
echo join(',&nbsp;', array_filter([$var1, $var2]));
```

`array_filter` removes all empty values, and `join` puts the joiner between the remaining items, *if there are more than one.*

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by many way e.g by **checking empty**, **using ternary** and so on but I've one way to fix this using `array_filter()` to remove empty values and implode with `,&nbsp;`. Then it'll not floating when any of the variable is empty string and it can consume multiple variables. Hope this helps :)

```
<?php
 $implode = ',&nbsp;';
 $var1 = 'xyz';
 $var2 = '';
 $result = [$var1,$var2];
 $filtered_result = array_filter($result);
 echo implode($implode,$filtered_result);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/PZ8Rv

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if(!(empty($var1) && empty($var2))){
echo $var1 . ',&nbsp;'.$var2;
}else{
$value = !empty($var1)? $var1 : (!empty($var2)? $var2 : "both are empty");
echo $value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your right condition use `||` operator which returns a boolean. if the right statement or left statement is true it will return true (1), or it will return false (0)

then you have to do something like this

```
 echo ($var1 && $var2 ? $var1 . ',&nbsp;' . $var2 : ($var1 ? $var1 : $var2));
```

note that $var1 has to be defined (null or empty but it has to be defined)

Comment: At the very least `$var1 ? $var1 : $var2` can be condensed to `$var1 ?: $var2`…

Comment: better yet to use `(!empty($var1) && !empty($var2) ? $var1. ' ' .$var2 : '');`

Comment: @trey Why the use of `empty`…?!

Comment: @treyBake it doens't produce the same output

Comment: @RomMer it works also, not far from what I tested. Thank you.

Comment: @deceze `When both of them are not empty I want something like this` <- just going for not empty values to concat

Comment: @RomMer oh snap! I've missed something :o :(

Comment: @trey "Empty" doesn't always mean you need `empty`, in most cases you just want `!$var`/`$var == true`/`$var`.

Comment: @deceze huh, I guess that makes sense o.O +1 to productivity!